# cannot setup react-boilerplate on mac M1

Tags: reactjs, macos, apple-m1, react-boilerplate

when I clone the repository and run this command "npm run start", this error occurs

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/hf/Downloads/leadbook-test/node_modules/ngrok
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./postinstall.js
npm ERR! ngrok - platform darwinarm64 is not supported.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hf/.npm/_logs/2022-03-09T19_45_14_908Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

`npm cache clean --force`

After that delete node_modules and package-lock.json

`npm install` or `yarn`

`npm start` or `yarn start`

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I've tried it and still get the same error

Comment: This error is specific to the node.js environment. maybe there is some issue with the installed version, let's try to upgrade it or downgrade it.